# jQuery multi part if statement not working

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I have a jQuery Mobile form I am working on where when the user tries to submit the form I would like to check the settings of 2 inputs.  The first input is a jquery mobile flipswitch and the second is a checkbox.

If my flipswitch value is 1 and my checkbox is checked I would like to throw and error.  The jQuery code below is not working for me.  Pretty sure I'm on the right track but I don't know what I am doing wrong here.  Anyone have any ideas?

my HTML

```
<select name="flip-min" id="flip-min" data-role="slider">
    <option id="filled" value="1">Filled</option>
    <option id="notFilled" value="0">Un-Filled</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="unable" id="unable"/>
<label for="unable">label text</label>

<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
```

my jQuery

```
$("input[name=submit]").on("click", function(){
    if($('#unable').is(':checked') && $('#flip-min').val() == 1){
        alert "error message";
        exit;
    }
});
```

Comment: try `alert("error message")`;

Comment: Your [JS Console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) should tell you about a syntax error on that `alert` line.

Comment: lol its always the easy stuff...wow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright, there appears to be a few things wrong with your code. First, there is no parenthesis around your alert function. This will definitely cause an error. Secondly, you have "exit;" at the end of the if statement when in reality, you want to use "return;". Here is what your code should look like:

```js
$("input[name=submit]").on("click", function(){
    if($('#unable').is(':checked') && $('#flip-min').val() == 1){
        alert("error message");
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

'alert' is a function, so you have to call it setting the arguments within parentheses as follows.

```
alert("error message");
```

and instead exit you have to put 'return;'

Answer (score 0):

@Austin, your code is correct But the **alert syntax** is incorrect!!!

**Correct syntax**

```
alert ("I have an error...!");
```

Also you can use **console.log** + development tools of your browser **(F12)** to monitor your messages and objects values.

**Correct code + console.log statement**

```
$("input[name=submit]").on("click", function(){
    if($('#unable').is(':checked') && $('#flip-min').val() == 1){
        console.log('I have an error...!');
        alert ("I have an error...!");
    }
});
```

**Result**
[image]

I used [**Firefox**](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-stub&os=win&lang=en-US) + [**Firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/) in my answer ;)